# Display arrangement settings for second monitor on top of laptop

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, mouse, display

I'm using a laptop with a second monitor in portrait mode above it. Like this:

```
       __
      |  |
      | 2|
      |__|
    _______
   |   1   |
   |_______|
```

I can't find settings that let me access the second screen by moving the mouse to the top of the laptop screen. Currently I need to move the mouse to the left of the laptop to access the second monitor. 
**Is it possible to access the top monitor by moving the mouse to the top on the bottom monitor?**

Edit: I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu you want help with, yes you can have a vertical arrangement (I use it myself on a couple of boxes, plus one monitor in portrait in a dual setup) - but your release influences the setup, and you haven't told us that.

Comment: What is your desktop environment? The solution will depend on it.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, it's Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: @N0rbert I don't know what you mean. How can I found out which desktop environment I'm using?

Comment: Not sure what your intention is, move to the top monitor if you move to the top of the bottom monitor, no matter on which x position the mouse is on the bottom monitor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to settings > Displays

And drag the second display to your desired position, then click on Apply.

[image: screen shot of screen settings page]

Comment: That was so simple!

Comment: You are a life saver!

Answer (score 6):

You could use ARandR, which is an XRandR GUI. It functions as a screen layout editor, in which you can rearrange your screens in any position you'd like as well as change the orientation of a screen (that would be helpful if your monitor doesn't support that option in its own controls).

Run the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt install arandr
```

You can see a screenshot of it being used [here](http://screenshots.debian.net/package/arandr):
[image: You can see a screenshot of it being used here: http://screenshots.debian.net/package/arandr]