# Display arrangement for second monitor on top of laptop

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell

When I try to set up a second monitor on top of my laptop display in Ubuntu 18.04, it is not working.

[image: Displays settings dialog]

What should I be doing to get this to work?

Comment: Related: [Display arrangement settings for second monitor on top of laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138593/display-arrangement-settings-for-second-monitor-on-top-of-laptop)